# Dual Boot Macos and Linux Macbook 16 inch 2019 issue

Tags: linux, dual-boot, macos

I am trying to install any form of Linux for dual boot onto my 2019 16 inch MacBook pro, I was able to do it onto my desktop pc but when I tried to run the install on my mac I kept getting a grub fatal error and it would never install, any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. I tried with regular Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Kali Linux and they all gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Previously (one year ago) I was able to install fedora on the same model, but there was no driver for the internal keyboard and wifi. I did a lot of research and didn't find any solution.

Your problem is most probably in T2 chip - secure boot. You need to turn off this in BIOS : https://www.wikihow.com/Turn-Off-Secure-Boot-on-Mac

Comment: It would be best to include the four steps from the link, in your answer, becasuee when the [link dies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), then your answer will not be so useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/415065)